# Why is this MSKB article not viewable on some systems?

Tags: internet, website, web

Once in a great while, I get a real **head-scratcher**.

The following link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945011
does not work as expected on some systems, but does on others.

On some systems, it **always** generates the message:

> Sorry, the page you requested is not available.

*(Note that this message has the Microsoft Support header on it.)*

Whereas on other systems it **always** brings up the appropriate MSKB article.

Other MSKB articles display fine on all systems.

There is nothing that should be interfering with loading this particular page on any of the systems.

Does anyone else experience this issue *(can you see the MSKB article?)* or know why some systems consistently cannot display that particular page, but can display all other MSKB articles just fine?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "some systems" and "other systems"?

Comment: @slhck Thanks for the comment.  I sent an email asking 18 different friends to try the link.  17 have replied so far.  Of those, 12 see the MSKB article just fine, and 5 get the "page not available" message.  What do you get?

Comment: "Works for me", but I'm on a Mac on a "normal" German DSL connection without Internet proxies or anything. What I meant by my comment was… have you tried getting info on which location, OSes, ISPs, etc. result in the page not being available? That might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @slhck Good question, and thank you for the data point.  I'm trying to see what, if anything is in common.  The really, really, strange thing is that it is just that one MSKB page.  Others work fine.  I'm perplexed.

Comment: @Ramhound I sent out a link to the 5 people reporting the error.  3 have responded.  Of those, only changing 'support' to 'support2' in the URL fixes the issue.  So it seems like maybe a bug with some of their servers and not others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not determined an absolutely conclusive answer to this question, but from what I can tell, it was due to a server-side error.